# New to C, using user input in multiple functions

Tags: c, input

I'm trying to create multiple functions using the same user input, I'm starting with decimal so I have an input function and the output

Next I'm going to do hexadecimal/ 8 bit binary and so on but I think I have the syntax wrong. I'm confused, I thought that you called the user input from main but I don't think that's correct.

Is there any advice anyone has that can help  ? It says the variables are conflicting

```
  #include <stdio.h>
 int main (void)
 {
   int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    in_decimal();
   out_decimal(x);

     }

    int in_decimal(void) {

     printf(" Please type in a decimal:");

     }


  void out_decimal(int x;){
    printf("%d",&x);
    }
```

Comment: You have to write function prototypes before main! Also `void out_decimal(int x;)` Semicolon too much! And `printf("%d",&x);` remove the &. Also add a return statement in main and in_Decimal since both have the return type int

Comment: Okay great thanks very much for your helpful response :) so for my other functions do I have to declare separate variables ? I want different outputs for the same input ? I'm very confused on that is main the ONLY input and I'm able to use it throughout all functions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this uncompleted code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

unsigned int in_decimal();
void out_decimal(unsigned int x);

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int x;
    x = in_decimal();
    out_decimal(x);

}

unsigned int in_decimal() 
{
    printf("Please type in a decimal: ");
    int ch;
    unsigned int x = 0;
    do
    {
        ch = getchar();
        if( ch < '0' || ch > '1')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            x *= 2;
            x += ch - '0';
        }
    }
    while( ch != '\n'); 
    return x;
}


void out_decimal(unsigned int x){
    if(x > 0)
    {
        out_decimal(x/2);
    }
    putchar('0' + x%2);
}
```

Now  `out_decimal()` is recursive function and always output 0 at the beginning of numbers that are greater than zero. Think what you can change :-)

Comment: You can use and change as you will. And also you can rate my answer :-)